# Time to replace The Joel Test?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Job posting in StackOverflow (although I have not seen it in recently postings) have the Joel Test grade attached to them. It is 12-software development practices a company should be using. The number of practices used give candidates an idea of the quality of a company's development environment. See: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html

It was written 15 years ago and is woefully dated. I suggest a different standard and its listed below:

1. Have Automated test suite: All levels of code should have test suite- basically code should tell you if it has a problem. Just like a mechanic can use a computer for diagnosis. The test suite should include- Unit test and Integration/BDD Test. UI Test, CSS test may be used depending on application-type. The sense if to reduce human-testing error and reduce the cost of human testing.
2. Continuous Integration: Code should be built on check-in. There should not be manual step to move code between environments- It should be automated.
3. Continuous Deployment: Code should be frequently given to the consumers in an automated fashion. You should not have to wait months after a bug or feature is complete before giving it to consumers
4. Source Control with versioning, branching and tagging. You should be able to rollback changes, tag a version and do many other things that alleviate worries of the consequences of having to undo changes or being able to access code. Two people should be able to work on the same codebase without much worry
5. Have a living spec vetted by everyone involved in its implementation (Developers [intern - VPs], UX Designers, etc): Everyone should be an expert and understand the business and problem addressed. The specs should be updated as business needs changes- it should be a living document.
6. Continuous stream of user feedback rather than a giant pile at completion of a project: Feedback of users should be welcomed and addressed quickly. The software development should be be so lagged that feedback is considered a burden
7. Have Coding Standards: It is great that developers think differently. Within reason, code should be written in a way that makes it easy for anyone to learn API's and read others' code. There some be some sense of uniformity
8. Have Code Reviews: Everyone should have their code critiqued by at least one peer prior to release. Bad-code should be corrected prior to release.
9. Test and Prod environments should mirror each other: This help alleviate some issues that happen in Prod but not in test environment.
10. Should be easy to get a manage running with the code base and dependencies; like with a container: It should not take many person-hours to get a new developer up-and-about. There should be a configuration that install all dependencies
11. Developers and business owners should meet regularly to talk about progress and challenges: Issues should be addressed sooner rather than later. Every should have an idea of the progress of the project and the sense of where they are in the timeline.
12. Tracking system should be used to keep track of progress rather than word-of-mouth or other means: You should be able to know what someone has done, is doing and will do without having to ask. Bug, features, and progress should  be logged and visible for all relevant persons to examine.

Does anyone see merit to this?

Comment: Depends. The Joel Test is several scrollbars long, and details everything about what was wrong in the industry versus developers at the time it was posted, I believe. Your post barely amounts to another table of contents in the aforementioned test -- are you *really* willing to flesh it out so it might supersede it?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Yeah, I am willing to flesh it out. However, I need some community feedback to make sure the core-principle are reasonable and are okay; before exerting the effort to write a well-though-out  post.  Do you think my ideas are on the right track?

Comment: I see. You're assuming a community effort would fare better than a single, right place at the right time, blog post from a prominent figure (our cofounder, after all). I suppose I also need community feedback to decide whether it's a good idea or not ;)

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Please, do not assume with me. If you are the last part of the question, I ask if there is merit to this. It need not be overcomplicated and no one should be afraid to rethink someone else's idea.

Comment: Okay, you seem to be serious about this. So, getting back to my first comment, just go ahead and fill out at least some of your bullet points, and get other people to follow in your stead. That said, I'm pretty sure Meta is not the right medium to do that.

Comment: Err... that close reasons are a bust: meta is the only way to communicate with both jobs and careers teams which are dependent of the SO product and "Does anyone see merit to this?" seems pretty straightforward asking for community input.

Comment: Agree that the test is dated. I can't speak to the merit of your proposal (not a dev), but posts like this will encourage our team to continue thinking about the feature and (I hope) work it into our roadmap.

Answer (score 15):

The nice thing about [the Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) is that it applies to pretty much every development house. Every developer, even a one-man "team", will be undeniably better off with all of those things. Source control is something no coder should ever be without.

Notice that Joel *did not* suggest which source control. He just said to have one. And that's very important. You can argue about whether Git is better than Mercurial or whether either is better than Subversion, or whether they're better than CVS. But you can't argue that it's better for a programmer to have *no* version control at all.

Your variation of this test is different because it picks sides. Your test is really a test for how agile, test-driven, and rapid-cycling a team's development methodology is. That's not solving the problem the Joel Test solves. Your test essentially asserts that agile and test-driven is fundamentally superior for all developers in all circumstances.

For example, for some products, it's basically impossible to have "Continuous Deployment" of releases. In those cases, that's just not how the product works. While an increasing number of videogames do have more frequent, continuous releases, there are still plenty which don't. Which release as a single, finished artistic work.

Who are you to say that the way they develop their games is wrong?

The Joel Test is not about methodology; it's not about how you go about development within your team. It's about whether programmers have the *essential tools* that would improve *every* methodology. The Joel Test applies to every developer equally, whether it's a thousand-strong team or one guy working on some code.

Yours does not.

Answer (score 14):

Revisiting the test is surely never wrong. The fact that one of the site's Founding Fathers wrote it is no reason not to!

Not sure whether I agree your current version is an improvement, though.

Many of your points are specifics that logically follow from the points in the original text. Some, like the bit about user feedback, are specific to some lines of work that may not apply to all programming environments.

The original test is intentionally broad, I think, and that's a *good* thing - the only purpose a check-list test like this can have is to ensure that employers even have a general notion of certain Very Important Concepts Without Which Our Heads Would Explode.

In the end, a test probably can't relieve you from the responsibility to check a shop out and see whether it's enlightened (and hence, open to improvements like, say, 21st century testing practices, even if they don't do it 100% right now) or not.

That said, "do you do code reviews" and "do you have coding standards" would sound like great additions to the current test.

Some sort of community-sourced update to the Joel Test might be a cool idea - but it would have to be something done by the SE team to have traction and a chance of getting actually implemented.

Whether they're interested in that, only they can answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You made some good point. My intent is to be broad, too. I did not mention Agile or scrum or docker. Plus, some of it is more so using terminology like "Continuous delivery" to bring that to mind.